# Unknown directory type while generate file in custom folder : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am generating packing slip of an order. its directly generate successfully in Media directory. but we need to generate inside "packingslip" folder. (media/packingslip).

While we change directory media to custom we are getting below error.

```
Unknown directory type: 'pub\/media\/packingslip\
```

packing slip directory generated successfully but still, we are getting an error.

Can anyone know how we can resolve an issue?

```
$this->fileFactory->create(
            $fileName,
            $pdfFileData['filestream'],
            DirectoryList::MEDIA.'/packingslip',
            'application/pdf'
        );
```

Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Initialize filesystem object via constructor.

```
 public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,\Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem
    ) {        
         $this->filesystem=$filesystem;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

Update Your Code with below :

```
$mediapath = $this->filesystem->getDirectoryRead(\Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList::MEDIA)->getAbsolutePath(); 
    $this->fileFactory->create(
                $fileName,
                $pdfFileData['filestream'],
                $mediapath.'packingslip',
                'application/pdf'
            );
```

Comment: You must have to create packingslip Directory under pub/media Directory.

Comment: still we are getting the same error. "Unknown directory type"

Comment: print $mediapath.'packingslip' path & check the path you are getting is correct one or not.

Comment: its giving me correct path but magento not allowed to generate file

Comment: Have you created "packingslip" directory manually?

Comment: yes and given 777 permission.

Comment: I have the same error, anyone revolve it? I have rute "pub/media/folder/" with 777 but return same error...